# Regression analysis ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have done multiple linear regression. I have tried to plot it with this command.

```
layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,4),2,2)) 
plot(fit_ec_urban_franchise)
```

After that I have 4 plots 'residuals vs. fitted', 'scale vs. location', 'normal q-q' and 'residuals vs.leverage'.

Is it possible use `ggplot2` to fit the 4 plots into one?

Comment: look for packages with `autoplot.lm` functions such as http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/eeptools/docs/autoplot.lm

Comment: Thanks for the help. Do you know another way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution is to use `ggplot2::fortify`. Here is the code you can find on its help page `?fortify`. I'm adding `gridExtra` to arrange the 4 plots together.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

mod <- lm(mpg ~ wt + cyl, data = mtcars)

p1 <- qplot(.fitted, .resid, data = mod) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE)

p2 <- qplot(sample =.stdresid, data = mod, stat = "qq") + geom_abline()

p3 <- qplot(.fitted, sqrt(abs(.stdresid)), data = mod) + geom_smooth(se = FALSE)

p4 <- qplot(.hat, .stdresid, data = mod) + geom_smooth(se = FALSE)


grid.arrange(p1,p2,p3,p4)
```

[image]

Comment: How I can add a main title? Is it possible to use `top`.

Comment: + ggtitle("your title here")

Comment: How can I add change smooth method because I stumble upon this error?   `geom_smooth: method="auto" and size of largest group is <1000, so using loess. Use 'method = x' to change the smoothing method.
Error: stat_smooth requires the following missing aesthetics: x, y`.

Comment: those are two different problems. The first is just a warning that geom_smooth is using `method=loess` ; change it in geom_smooth if you will, but that works. The second means there is something wrong with your data or code, since it cannot find x and y ; either you did not map anything to x and y in the plot's aes() or your data is somehow corrupted

Comment: @scoa.I fix the problem. Thank you for your kindness. I owe you one.